# Ganache-Cli Error: Digital Envelope Routines Unsupported

Tags: ganache-cli

When running the command `ganache-cli` in Git Bash, I get the following error.

[image: Error]

I have already installed Truffle and Ganache-Cli, and I've even tried on Powershell and the Windows command prompt (all ran as admin), but to no avail.

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the current version of NodeJS, try uninstalling NodeJS completely and downgrade it to the latest LTS version.

[image: NodeJS Installation Page]